# How to avoid adding prefix “unsafe” to link by Angular-2?

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic2

I am developing a mobile app using `angular2` and `ionic 2`,
I have 3 `buttons` for `call`, `sms` and `email` as below

```
          <a ion-button href="tel:{{contact.cellphone}}" color="primary">
            <ion-icon name="call"></ion-icon>
            Call
          </a>
          <a ion-button href="sms:{{contact.cellphone}}" color="secondary">
            <ion-icon name="text"></ion-icon>
            SMS
          </a>
          <a ion-button href="mailto:{{contact.email}}" color="dark">
            <ion-icon name="mail"></ion-icon>
            Email
          </a>
```

`Call` and `email` are working fine, but not `sms`, it seems angular adds `unsafe:` in-front of my expression and it will become like below

```
<a color="secondary" ion-button="" ng-reflect-color="secondary" class="button button-md button-default button-default-md button-md-secondary" ng-reflect-href="unsafe:sms:+16475374201" href="unsafe:sms:+16475374201"><span class="button-inner">
```

even I tried this

```
      <a ion-button [attr.href]="'sms:'+contact.cellphone" color="secondary">
        <ion-icon name="text"></ion-icon>
        SMS
      </a>
```

still same issue,

When I don't use angular binding it's working fine, for example like this

```
          <a ion-button href="sms:+1647654654" color="secondary">
            <ion-icon name="text"></ion-icon>
            SMS
          </a>
```

Although it's related to angular but also I checked my `config.xml` and `sms` is allowed there

```
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
```

### Update

After using @Apuu solution it become like below

```
          <a ion-button [attr.href]="'sms:'+contact.cellphone | safeUrl" color="secondary">
            <ion-icon name="text"></ion-icon>
            SMS
          </a>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create a pipe service to change unsafe url to safe url.

Create a pipe service called `safe-url.pipe.ts`.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
@Pipe({
  name: 'safeUrl'
})
export class SafeUrlPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
  transform(url) {
    return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
}
}
```

Then use in your view.
Example :

```
<a ion-button [src]="'some_url' | safeUrl" color="secondary">
     <ion-icon name="text"></ion-icon>
     SMS
</a>
```

**NOTE** : Don't forget to inject this pipe service in your app.module.ts

```
import { SafeUrlPipe } from './shared/safe-url.pipe'; //make sure your safe-url.pipe.ts file path is matching.
```

And in your node module declarations section.

```
@NgModule({ declarations: [SafeUrlPipe],...});
```

Comment: nice example, thanks

Comment: You are most welcome @AvtandilKavrelishvili, keep coding ....

Comment: Also worth noting that in this specific case, you can't cobble the URL protocol together in the template. Instead, any link (like a tel or sms link) would need the protocol appended onto it.   `<a [href]="phoneNumber | safeUrl"></a>`, where `phoneNumber` is `tel:...`