# pass value to an href tag in typescript ionic

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

How to set the value to href tag from my input field. When user will click the value of href tag which is ="skype:+ (value from input)? should call.

```
<ion-content padding>
    <ion-col>
         <ion-label color="primary">Enter The No.</ion-label>
    <ion-input placeholder="Text Input"></ion-input>
      <a href="skype:+jelordrey?call">
    <button  ion-button color="secondary">test</button>
     </a>
       <!--  <a href="skype:+jelordrey?call">
               <button >
                        Click to open Skype and dial the no:+1234567890
              </button>
      </a> -->
 </ion-col>

</ion-content>
export class SkypecallPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad SkypecallPage');
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an input to take data from the user. So you have to first use ngModel on that ion-input so that you can bind the model name to your href attribute:

So use the following in your html:

```
<ion-item>
   <ion-label color="primary">Enter The No.</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Number" [(ngModel)]="userNumber"></ion-input>  //you can use any model name and declare it in your ts
</ion-item>
```

and then use that ngModel value to bind it in your href attribute using [attr.href]:

```
<a>[attr.href]="'skype:+' + userNumber + '?call'"</a>
```

and as SAJ said it can throw you an "sanitizing unsafe URL value" warning then use DomSanitizer and you will be good to go.
Use the same [stack-overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40754050/how-to-avoid-adding-prefix-unsafe-to-link-by-angular-2) as SAJ has mentioned to check how you can handle unsafe url

Answer (score 1):

You can use [attr.href] option to dynamically set the href value. The code will look something like shown below

```
<a [attr.href]="'skype:+' + name + '?call'">
 <button ion-button color="secondary">test</button>
</a>
```

If angluar is detecting it as unsafe url by prefixing unsafe: string in href while doing the above, you might have to make it safe url using dom sanitizer. You can check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40754050/how-to-avoid-adding-prefix-unsafe-to-link-by-angular-2) to see how to use dom sanitizer