# Android browser intent link with dynamic query params

Tags: android, angular, google-chrome

Tried to pass dynamic params (e.g. user token) from Angular app to Android app, works fine with
static query params, but link is not opened with dynamic ones...

Link is opened:

```
<a href="intent://dummyIntent?token=12345/#Intent;scheme=https;package=net.openid.appauthdemo S.browser_fallback_url=http%3A%2F%2Fa-fallback-url;end">App</a>
```

Link is not opened:

```
<a href="intent://dummyIntent?token={{user.token}}/#Intent;scheme=https;package=net.openid.appauthdemo S.browser_fallback_url=http%3A%2F%2Fa-fallback-url;end">App</a>
```

Also tried extra param, same problem:

```
<a href="intent://dummyIntent/#Intent;scheme=https;package=net.openid.appauthdemo S.browser_fallback_url=http%3A%2F%2Fa-fallback-url;S.token={{user.token}};end">App</a>
```

Hint: Link is shown as "unsafe" if copied to clipboard

```
unsafe:intent://dummyIntent?token=/#Intent;scheme=https;package=net.openid.appauthdemo;end
```

Any suggestions to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution: Used a safeUrl-Pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
@Pipe({
  name: 'safeUrl'
})
export class SafeUrlPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
  transform(url) {
    return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
}
}
```

Template:

```
<a [attr.href]="intentLink | async | safeUrl">App</a>
```

[How to avoid adding prefix “unsafe” to link by Angular-2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40754050/how-to-avoid-adding-prefix-unsafe-to-link-by-angular-2)